# BroadcastReceiver and ResultReceiver in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

What is difference between BroadcastReceiver and ResultReceiver in android? Can somebody share any example? I have gone through [here](http://www.techwars.io/fight/resultreceiver/broadcastreceiver/). 
but I need more explanation.

Comment: You should show your effort first here. What have you tried?